# New Angular project created without package.json, angular.json, etc

Tags: angular, package.json, workspace, new-project, angular14

I decided to create a library for Angular as a way to learn a bit more about it. I work every day with Angular but have never set up a project from scratch. I've never had to actually deal with an empty environment, create the backbones of a project, the first CSS classes and so on.

I also decided to do this on the currently latest version of Angular (14) to also learn what new it has to offer (I work with Angular 8 at work), so maybe my problem is just that it changed over time and I'm assuming things wrong.

### That being said, here is my issue:

Angular documentation says I should create a workspace for working with libs if I want to use the lib without publishing it. Since I'm still not sure if I'll ever publish this, that's what I did. So I created a workspace called angular-14. It aparently also set up a git repo automatically, but I removed the .git and .gitignore because I plan on versioning each project separately:

[image]

Then, I created my library project under the `projects` folder, which looks like this by default:

[image]

So far, so good. Now, lets create an application project that will use this library, and here comes the issue:

[image]

No `angular.json`, `package.json` or `package-lock.json`. I was also expecting it to have a `tsconfig.json` and not only `tsconfig.app.json`.

Does that mean I'll have to rely on the files present in the workspace (and therefore I'm stuck and will have to version the whole workspace)? Or should I manually create these files?

I noticed it because WebStorm didn't set up the run/debug configuration automatically. `ng-serve` is working as intended, though.

It also didn't create an `e2e` folder, but that I assume is just that I forgot to add some parameter in the project creation. This is probably not going to be a product, so I will focus on learning just the library development thing for now.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes. Turns out this is all normal Angular. Normal applications also work inside workspaces but the project files are merged with the workspace files. When we need to make a lib, it requires to separate the project in a Projects folder. This is intended for people to have multiple projects sharing the same configuration.

This doesn't help me though as if I decide to make only one project inside the workspace open source, I'll have a problem. So what I'm going to do instead is to just create a dummy application inside this workspace to test the library and in case I actually decide to use this in a project, I'll have to publish it and use it like everyone else would.